# Webpack: All code splitting chunks being downloaded with prefetch

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I have 3 main code split chunks, main.x.js, 0.x.js and 1.x.js.

I'm splitting with require.ensure, and have also tried the new simple Promise syntax for splitting. The code splitting itself seems to work perfectly, the 3 chunks get output and using the HTML visualizer I can see them only include the code I want.

However, when I open the main page of the app, webpack seems to be loading all my code splitted chunks immediately using "prefetch" on the main page. I can see this in devtools as Purpose: prefetch on the 0.js and 1.js chunks. main.js is loaded "normally".

When I then navigate to a part of the site that requires 0.x.js, I can see chrome firing a "normal" request to retrieve 0.x.js. So it seems as if the splitting and run-time loading is (sort of) working correctly.

However, I don't want this prefetching behaviour, as the reason I am using the code splitting in the first place is to save users bandwidth from parts of the site that they won't use. Is there any way to turn off this prefetching behaviour?

This is with webpack 2.7.0.

Comment: Is your `require.ensure` call in the top level of a file you import or in a function you call later?  (e. g. when is the `require.ensure` called?)

Comment: Hi Sean, the require.ensures are at the top, but I'm using Vue's lazy loading (https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html) to (hopefully) only load the components when they are needed.

It does feel as if it's on the webpack side, because I can see an additional "normal" request for for example 1.x.js when I navigate to a part of that site that uses that chunk, which makes me think that for some reason all chunks are being loaded in the beginning, but the additional ones in this Purpose: prefetch mode, which is what I don't want.

Comment: I just checked, and this has got something to do with Vue server side rendering.

If I built it as a normal SPA, then everything works fine. The other chunks are only loaded (not even with Purpose: prefetch) only when I navigate.

It is only when I built it as a vue SSR app that the Purpose: prefetch is applied to all resources on the main page load.

Perhaps someone can point me to where to start digging to find the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, after realising after Sean's comment that its not webpack at fault here.

The "problem" was the vue-server-renderer createBundleRenderer function, as per the docs here https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/api.html#renderer-options, the trick was the shouldPreload and shouldPrefetch functions.

Simply adding:

```js
 shouldPrefetch: (file, type) => {
   // 0.js, 1.js
   return false;
 },
 shouldPreload: (file, type) => {
   // main.js, manifest.js
   return true;
 },
```

to the createBundleRenderer options solved the issue for me.